# Is my Chaos Genasi subrace balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, homebrew-review, races

I recently created a Chaos Genasi subrace that has origins in the elemental chaos. They are meant to have a small amount of power from each of the elemental planes. I made them to be flexible and able to play as most classes.

**Chaos Genasi**

Where other Genasi are from one of the Elemental planes, you are from the Elemental Chaos, where all elements mingle.

- **Ability Score Increase**: One of your ability scores (other than
  Constitution) increases by 1
- **Elemental Absorber**: Your exposure to the Elemental Chaos has given
  you a limited ability to absorb elements. You can cast the Absorb
  Elements spell once, and you regain the ability to do so when you
  finish a long rest. Constitution is your spellcasting ability for
  this spell.
- **Survivor in the Chaos**: Your time in the elemental chaos has made you
  skilled at adapting to any climate. You are naturally adapted to hot
  and cold climates  - you don't have to make the saving throws to avoid exhaustion while exposed to extreme climates - and have proficiency in the Survival skill.

Comment: Just a thought, generally it’s better to wait some amount of time before accepting an answer, as other users may intend to be provide different perspectives, but would be discouraged from doing so if an answer is already accepted.

Comment: You can up vote it without accepting it, if it is helpful to you, but @ThomasMarkov is right about being patient.  A better answer may arrive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It isn't unbalanced

The Genasi race from the Elemental Evil Players Companion, when compared with other races, isn't in the top third of 'power' assessments done by a variety of analysis.  [A recent assessment finds](https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?625780-Detect-Greater-Balance-%96-A-Critical-Review-of-5e-Race-Design&highlight=balance) them all in the low to mid range, power wise.  They range from Air (19) to Water (25) on the scoring there with the top races earning a (32). (I disagree with the vHuman assessment of 33, but that's not a concern for your question).

[image]
Detailed spread sheet [is here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vq1kz6PRAbw5LHy6amH-bNb4OuB8DBXL1RsZROt03Sc/edit#gid=0).

#### Caveat

I recommend reading the whole analysis, and some of the discussions in the linked thread.  Each attempt by non-WoTC folks to assess balance between race choices has pros and cons.  I think this one is a pretty thorough look, and the scoring is reasonable - but it's not the only approach that people use to assess how many features to have or not to have.

#### Compared to Water Genasi: close, but not as good

> Ability Score Increase. Your Wisdom score increases by 1.

Your flexible ASI is better by a bit, and allows optimization approaches in more classes.  Similar to vHuman and Half Elf flexibility. +1 to Chaos Genasi.  Maybe +2, since that kind of character generating/building flexibility can allow you to his some 'stat sweet spots' across the board.

> Acid Resistance. You have resistance to acid damage.

Yours has no resistances, but exhaustion prevention in some climates is comparable.  A wash.

> Amphibious. You can breathe air and water.

Yours doesn' have that; you have Survival skill.  A wash, but it's also campaign dependent.

> Swim. You have a swimming speed of 30 feet.

Yours has nothing. (+2 to Water Genasi).

> Call to the Wave. You know the shape water cantrip (see chapter 2).
> When you reach 3rd level, you can cast  the create or destroy water
> spell as a 2nd-level spell  once with this trait, and you regain the
> ability to cast it  this way when you finish a long rest. Constitution
> is your spellcasting ability for these spells.

You offer a comparable spell benefit that has wide application, though I think the Water Genasi may have the edge here.  Maybe a +1 to Water.

Overall: somewhere in the low to mid twenties on that spread sheet, all said and done. I scored the Water Genasi as +7 and your Chaos Genasi at +6 (or +5, depends on how you judge the spell) using the spread sheet - for a 24 or a 23 - based on the "Guide" tab in the linked spread sheet.  But that assessment may be off by a point or two. There's some subjectivity in how the scoring is assigned, and the 'value' of a given feature.

That supports "Not Unbalanced" as an assessment.  Water is in the 'sweet spot' at 25 (range from 19-32 puts the median at about 25). Your is closer to a 24.  You need not be concerned with *unbalance* on this, given the range of values used for scoring.

Comment: Thank you. Helps a lot. No, the adapted to hot and cold climates just prevents exhaustion through those climates